# HTML element attached to JS object

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I just stater a bit of OOJS but I can't get my head around one thing, making an object for and HTML element and adding events to it.

For practice sake I had an idea to make inputs that can be validated, edited etc...

Here is how I call the input and assign it the HTML object

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-field');

for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
  var instance = new input(elements[n]);
}
```

And this **actually** works, the event is assigned

[image: Asigned event]

But when I click on the input `this.element` is undefined, I really don't know how because I already constructed the object with `this.element` assigned.

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';

 var Input = function Input(elem) {
  this.element = elem;
  this.construct();
 };

 Input.prototype.Classes = {
  INPUT: 'input-field__input',
  LABEL: 'input-field__label',
  EDITED: 'input-field--edited',
  FOCUSED: 'input-field--focused'
 };

 Input.prototype.onFocus_ = function(e) {
  this.element.classList.add(this.Classes.FOCUSED);
 };

 Input.prototype.construct = function() {
  if(this.element) {
   this.input = this.element.querySelector('.' + this.Classes.INPUT);
   this.label = this.element.querySelector('.' + this.Classes.LABEL);

   if(this.input){
    this.input.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus_);
   }
  }

 }


 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-field');
 for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
  var instance = new Input(elements[n]);
 }
})()
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <label class="input-field__label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="input-field__input">
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <label class="input-field__label">Last</label>
  <input type="text" name="last" class="input-field__input">
</div>
```

The problem is that the event is assigned but it doesn't know which object is it, `this` is point to actual HTML input not the `Input` object.

**How do I fix this?**

I searched the web but couldn't find anything similar. Closest I found:
[JS objects attached to HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540797/js-objects-attached-to-html-elements)

Also if you can improve the code in any way please don't mind I am still learning.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bind` function to define scope your function will use. Currently your scope is your element, not your class instance.

```
this.input.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus_.bind(this));
```

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';

 var Input = function Input(elem) {
  this.element = elem;
  this.construct();
 };

 Input.prototype.Classes = {
  INPUT: 'input-field__input',
  LABEL: 'input-field__label',
  EDITED: 'input-field--edited',
  FOCUSED: 'input-field--focused'
 };

 Input.prototype.onFocus_ = function(e) {
  this.element.classList.add(this.Classes.FOCUSED);
 };

 Input.prototype.construct = function() {
  if(this.element) {
   this.input = this.element.querySelector('.' + this.Classes.INPUT);
   this.label = this.element.querySelector('.' + this.Classes.LABEL);

   if(this.input){
    this.input.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus_.bind(this));
   }
  }

 }


 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.input-field');
 for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
  var instance = new Input(elements[n]);
 }
})()
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <label class="input-field__label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="input-field__input">
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <label class="input-field__label">Last</label>
  <input type="text" name="last" class="input-field__input">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really stupid from me... I really forgot, because I usually write it on seperate link and add an evenetLisner to a bound function... :(